# Full Path can only be retrieved when a treenode has been added to a treeview. This TreeNode has not been added to a TreeView

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, treeview

I have Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008.

Now below are the steps I followed to create a OLEDB connection(this is the first time in this pc we are using BIDS)

1. Opened the Package.
2. right clicked in the connection managers space and selected OLEDB connection.
3. Then a pop up window came up having "New" option.
4. Now I clicked on it then this error gets displayed.

"Full Path can only be retrived when a treenode has been added to a treeview. This TreeNode has not been added to a TreeView"

[image]

Comment: An ole db connection to what?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, read the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll need to provide more details on the issue you're facing for the community to help you.

Comment: @billinkc I just try too create a connection but it does not allow me to do it. It does not show me the options(excel, Native SQL or Oracle). I have updated my question and provided the error image via link. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the advise @EduardMalakhov. I have now updated my statement and also provided the Image.